# Why am I getting an Uncommitted Work Pending error when deploying?

Tags: code-coverage, failing-tests

I am unable to deploy this code because I am getting an error stating the following when a test class is run on it.

This is the error :

```
System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out :


Stack Trace: 
Class.HTTPService_PARDOT.send: line 17, column 1 
Class.Http_Utility_Pardot.login: line 52, column 1 
Class.Http_Utility_Pardot.pardotCreateProspect: line 86, column 1 
Class.UpdateContactPCRController.updateContact: line 100, column 1 
Class.Test_UpdateContactPCRController.testUpdateContactPCRController: line 115, column 1
```

So, the Test_UpdateContactPCRController test class is initially calling UpdateContactPCRController, which in turn uses Http_Utility_Pardot, which ultimately uses HTTPService_Pardot.

I have included all of those classes and the test classes. I have also labeled the lines which are showing up in the errors.

**Here is the test class. The line which shows in the error is this :
String response = UpdateContactPCRController.updateContact(proContactRolesData[0].Id);**

```
 @isTest(seeAllData = false)
    private class Test_UpdateContactPCRController {
            @testSetUp static void testSetupData(){
            
            // Create a unique User records
            String uniqueUserName = 'standarduser' + DateTime.now().getTime() + '@testorg.com';
            // This code runs as the system user
            Profile profileTest = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User'];
    
            User userFrom = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com', EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', 
            LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = profileTest.Id, 
            TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName=uniqueUserName);
            
            User userTo = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com',EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing', 
            LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = profileTest.Id, TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', 
            UserName=uniqueUserName);
    
            //Create Account records
            List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
            accounts.add(new Account(Name = 'AccountTest1'));
            accounts.add(new Account(Name = 'AccountTest2'));
            accounts.add(new Account(Name = 'AccountTest3'));
            insert accounts;
            
            //Create program records
            List<Program__c> programs = new List<Program__c>();
            programs.add(new Program__c(Name = 'ProgramDemo1',Buyer__c = accounts[0].Id));
            programs.add(new Program__c(Name = 'ProgramDemo2' , Buyer__c = accounts[1].Id));
            programs.add(new Program__c(Name = 'ProgramDemo3',Buyer__c = accounts[2].Id));
            insert programs;
    
            //Create contact records
            List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
            contacts.add(new Contact(FirstName = 'Contact' , LastName = 'Test1' , Email = 'sarj@gmail.com'));
            contacts.add(new Contact(FirstName = 'Contact' , LastName = 'Test2' , Email = 'sarj1@gmail.com'));
            contacts.add(new Contact(FirstName = 'Contact' , LastName = 'Test3' , Email = 'sarj2@gmail.com'));
            insert contacts;
    
           
            //Create program communication records
            List<Program_Communication__c> proCommunications = new List<Program_Communication__c>();
            proCommunications.add(new Program_Communication__c(Name='proCommunication1',Program__c = programs[0].Id , Logo_Public_Url__c = '&versionId=06856000000FXaEAAW&operationContext=DELIVERY&page=0&d=/a/560000008V0q/IQoWYqi_cIVSBG8rUl4x78lmbl0vtdIwnu7WpHoag0M&oid=00D560000009n7iEAA&dpt=null', Welcome_Message__c='Have a nice day.', Reply_to_Email__c= userTo.Id , From_Email__c= userFrom.Id));
            proCommunications.add(new Program_Communication__c(Name='proCommunication2',Program__c = programs[0].Id , Logo_Public_Url__c = '&versionId=06856000000FXaEAAW&operationContext=DELIVERY&page=0&d=/a/560000008V0q/IQoWYqi_cIVSBG8rUl4x78lmbl0vtdIwnu7WpHoag0M&oid=00D560000009n7iEAA&dpt=null',Welcome_Message__c='Have a nice day. Have a nice day.', Reply_to_Email__c= userTo.Id , From_Email__c= userFrom.Id));
            proCommunications.add(new Program_Communication__c(Name='proCommunication3',Program__c = programs[0].Id , Logo_Public_Url__c = '&versionId=06856000000FXaEAAW&operationContext=DELIVERY&page=0&d=/a/560000008V0q/IQoWYqi_cIVSBG8rUl4x78lmbl0vtdIwnu7WpHoag0M&oid=00D560000009n7iEAA&dpt=null',Welcome_Message__c='Have a nice day.', Reply_to_Email__c= userTo.Id , From_Email__c= userFrom.Id));
            insert proCommunications;
    
            //Create program contact role records
            List<Program_Contact_Role__c> proContactRoles = new List<Program_Contact_Role__c>();
            proContactRoles.add(new Program_Contact_Role__c(Name = 'ProContactRole1',Program_Name__c = programs[0].Id , Contact__c = contacts[0].Id));
            proContactRoles.add(new Program_Contact_Role__c(Name = 'ProContactRole2',Program_Name__c = programs[0].Id , Contact__c = contacts[1].Id));
            proContactRoles.add(new Program_Contact_Role__c(Name = 'ProContactRole3',Program_Name__c = programs[0].Id , Contact__c = contacts[2].Id));
            insert proContactRoles;
    
            //Create program communication recipients records
            List<Program_Communication_Recipients__c> proCommRecipients = new List<Program_Communication_Recipients__c>(); 
            proCommRecipients.add(new Program_Communication_Recipients__c(Program_Communication__c = proCommunications[0].Id,Receipient__c = proContactRoles[0].Id));
            proCommRecipients.add(new Program_Communication_Recipients__c(Program_Communication__c = proCommunications[0].Id,Receipient__c = proContactRoles[1].Id));
            proCommRecipients.add(new Program_Communication_Recipients__c(Program_Communication__c = proCommunications[0].Id,Receipient__c = proContactRoles[2].Id));
            insert proCommRecipients; 
        }
        
        static testMethod void testUpdateContactPCRController() {
            
            Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockProspectResponse());
            
            //Fetch program contact roles
            List<Program_Contact_Role__c> proContactRolesData = [Select Name, Program_Name__c From Program_Contact_Role__c];
            
            //Fetch program communication recipients record
            List<Program_Communication_Recipients__c> getProgramCommunicationRecs = [Select Id,Name,Program_Communication__r.Welcome_Message__c,
                                                                                  Program_Communication__r.Program__r.Buyer__r.Name,Receipient__c,
                                                                                  Program_Communication__r.Logo_Public_Url__c ,Welcome_Page_with_IDs__c, Program_Communication__r.URL_for_UI__c,
                                                                                  Program_Communication__r.Reply_to_Email__c, Program_Communication__r.From_Email__c
                                                                                  from Program_Communication_Recipients__c where 
                                                                                  Program_Communication__r.Program__c =: proContactRolesData[0].Program_Name__c AND 
                                                                                  Receipient__c =: proContactRolesData[0].Id];
            //Call method  to update contact records and send email to contact
            String response = UpdateContactPCRController.updateContact(proContactRolesData[0].Id);
            
            //Fetch contact list after update records successfully.
            List<Contact> updatedContacts = [Select Name , Pardot_Action_Trigger__c , Program_Contact_Role_Id__c , PCR_Register_Button_Link__c , PCR_URL_for_UI__c , PCR_Buyer_Name__c , PCR_Buyer_Logo_Url__c , PCR_Welcome_Message__c,From_Email__c,Reply_to_Email__c From Contact];
            
            
            //Check asserts for each value updated on contact records
            //Check pardot action trigger value, after updating its value Send Welcome Email.
            //After successfully updated contact recors  workflow fire and perform two actions. 
            //workflow perform email alert and field update action.
            System.assertEquals(getProgramCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.From_Email__c,updatedContacts[0].From_Email__c);
    
            
            //Check contact Reply_To_Email__c filed are populated or not
            System.assertEquals(getProgramCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.Reply_to_Email__c,updatedContacts[0].Reply_to_Email__c);
    
            //Check program contact role id is populated or not.
            System.assertEquals(proContactRolesData[0].Id,updatedContacts[0].Program_Contact_Role_Id__c);
            
            //Check PCR register button on contact updated by program communication field 'Welcome_Page_with_IDs__c'
            System.assertEquals(getProgramCommunicationRecs[0].Welcome_Page_with_IDs__c,updatedContacts[0].PCR_Register_Button_Link__c);
            
            //Check contact field PCR_URL_for_UI__c successfully updated or not
            System.assertEquals(getProgramCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.URL_for_UI__c , updatedContacts[0].PCR_URL_for_UI__c);
            
            //Check PCR_Buyer_Name__c field successfully updated or not
            System.assertEquals(getProgramCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.Program__r.Buyer__r.Name , updatedContacts[0].PCR_Buyer_Name__c);
            
            //Check PCR_Welcome_Message__c field successfully updated or not
            System.assertEquals(getProgramCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.Welcome_Message__c , updatedContacts[0].PCR_Welcome_Message__c);
     
            //Check PCR_Buyer_Logo_Url__c field successfully updated or not
            System.assertEquals(getProgramCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.Logo_Public_Url__c , updatedContacts[0].PCR_Buyer_Logo_Url__c);
    
            //Check record successfully updated or nor
            System.assertEquals('Updated Successfully',response);
            
           
        }
        
    }
```

**And that test class is initially calling this class and this line which calls the class I include later shows up in the error :
String returnedResponseFromPardot = Http_Utility_Pardot.pardotCreateProspect(new Set {contactToBeupdate[0].Id});
:**

```
public class UpdateContactPCRController {

    @AuraEnabled
    public static String  updateContact(String recordId){
        
        //Variable to hold the contact Id
        String contactId = '';
        
        //List ot update contact
        List<Contact> contactToBeupdate = new List<Contact>();
        
        //Check for contact record
        if(String.isNotBlank(recordId)){
            
            //Get Program Contact Role
            List<Program_Contact_Role__c> programContacList = [SELECT Id,Contact__c,Program_Name__c FROM Program_Contact_Role__c WHERE Id =:recordId AND Contact__c != null];
            
            if(programContacList.size() > 0)
                contactId = programContacList[0].Contact__c;
            
            if(String.isNotBlank(contactId)){
                
                contactToBeupdate = [Select Id,Pardot_Action_Trigger__c,PCR_Register_Button_Link__c,PCR_URL_for_UI__c FROM Contact Where Id =: contactId Limit 1];
                
                contactToBeupdate[0].Pardot_Action_Trigger__c = 'Send Welcome Email';
                contactToBeupdate[0].Program_Contact_Role_Id__c = recordId;
            }
            
2375 - Added new custom fileds From_Email__c, Reply_to_Email__c in query  
            //Update Buyer Name or Logo from Program and Program Communication to Contact
            List<Program_Communication_Recipients__c> programCommunicationRecs = [Select Id,Name,Program_Communication__r.Welcome_Message__c,
                                                                                         Program_Communication__r.Program__r.Buyer__r.Name,Receipient__c,
                                                                                         Program_Communication__r.Program__r.Buyer__r.Account_Name_for_Communications__c,
                                                                                         Program_Communication__r.Logo_Public_Url__c ,Welcome_Page_with_IDs__c, 
                                                                                         Program_Communication__r.URL_for_UI__c ,Program_Communication__r.Learn_More_link__c,
                                                                                         Program_Communication__r.Reply_to_Email__c,Program_Communication__r.From_Email__c                
                                                                                         From Program_Communication_Recipients__c Where 
                                                                                         Program_Communication__r.Program__c =: programContacList[0].Program_Name__c AND 
                                                                                         Receipient__c =: programContacList[0].Id];
                                                   
            //Check Recipient
            if(programCommunicationRecs.size() > 0){
                
                if(String.isNotBlank(programCommunicationRecs[0].Welcome_Page_with_IDs__c))
                    contactToBeupdate[0].PCR_Register_Button_Link__c = programCommunicationRecs[0].Welcome_Page_with_IDs__c;
                //Added condition to replace contactTriggerHelper logic
                
                //02 Dec 2019
                if(String.isNotBlank(programCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.Learn_More_link__c))
                            contactToBeupdate[0].PCR_Learn_More_Link__c = programCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.Learn_More_link__c;
                        
                if(String.isNotBlank(programCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.URL_for_UI__c))
                    contactToBeupdate[0].PCR_URL_for_UI__c = programCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.URL_for_UI__c;
                    
               //CHANGED TO USE Account.Account_Name_for_Communcations__c for Contact.PCR_Buyer_Name__c
               //WILL DEFAULT TO Account.Name IF Account.Account_Name_for_Communications__c IS BLANK
               
               if(String.isNotBlank(programCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.Program__r.Buyer__r.Account_Name_for_Communications__c))
                    contactToBeupdate[0].PCR_Buyer_Name__c = programCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.Program__r.Buyer__r.Account_Name_for_Communications__c;
               if(String.isBlank(programCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.Program__r.Buyer__r.Account_Name_for_Communications__c))
                    contactToBeupdate[0].PCR_Buyer_Name__c = programCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.Program__r.Buyer__r.Name;
               //END CHANGE
                
                if(String.isNotBlank(programCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.Welcome_Message__c) && String.valueOf(programCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.Welcome_Message__c).length()> 254)
                    contactToBeupdate[0].PCR_Welcome_Message__c = String.valueOf(programCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.Welcome_Message__c).substring(0, 254);
                else 
                    contactToBeupdate[0].PCR_Welcome_Message__c = String.valueOf(programCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.Welcome_Message__c);
                
                contactToBeupdate[0].PCR_Buyer_Logo_Url__c = programCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.Logo_Public_Url__c;
                

                contactToBeupdate[0].From_Email__c = programCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.From_Email__c;
                contactToBeupdate[0].Reply_to_Email__c = programCommunicationRecs[0].Program_Communication__r.Reply_to_Email__c;
            }
        }

  
        String returnedResponseFromPardot = Http_Utility_Pardot.pardotCreateProspect(new Set<Id> {contactToBeupdate[0].Id});

        if(contactToBeupdate.size() > 0){
            update contactToBeupdate;  
        }
        
        return 'Updated Successfully';
    }
}
```

**That class uses this class, and this line shows up on the error :**
**HttpResponse response = HTTPService_PARDOT.send(request);**

```
public with sharing class Http_Utility_Pardot {
        
        public static String login(Pardot_Tracking_Configuration__mdt pardotTrackingConfig) {
            
            String requestBody = 'email=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(pardotTrackingConfig.UserName__c, Constants.UTF_8)
                                    + '&password=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(pardotTrackingConfig.Passward__c, Constants.UTF_8)
                                    + '&user_key=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(pardotTrackingConfig.User_Key__c, Constants.UTF_8);
                     
            HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
            request.setEndpoint('callout:APEX_Pardot_Credential/account/version/4/do/read');
                            
            request.setHeader('Pardot-Business-Unit-Id', '0Uv560000004C98CAE');
            request.setMethod('POST');
            
            HttpResponse response = HTTPService_PARDOT.send(request);
    
            return HTTPResponseParser_PARDOT.parseLoginResponse(response);
            
        }
    
       public static String pardotCreateProspect(Set<Id> contactIds) {
            
            
            List<Pardot_Tracking_Configuration__mdt> pardotTrackingConfigs = [SELECT Id, Login_URL__c, UserName__c, Passward__c, User_Key__c,
                                                                                Email_Tracking_URL__c, Create_Prospect_Endpoint__c, Batch_Create_Prospect_Endpoint__c
                                                                                FROM Pardot_Tracking_Configuration__mdt WHERE DeveloperName = 'Pardot_Tracking_Data'];
            System.debug('***Http_Utility_Pardot post List referencing Pardot_Tracking_Configuration__mdt pardotTrackingConfigs ' + pardotTrackingConfigs);
            if(pardotTrackingConfigs.size() == 0)
                return System.Label.Pardot_Error_PTC_Not_Defined;
                          
            String apiKey = login(pardotTrackingConfigs[0]);
                 
            if(contactIds.size() == 0)
                return System.Label.Pardot_Error_Contact_Id_Missing;
                
            
            List<Contact> contacts = [SELECT Id, Email, FirstName, LastName, OwnerId FROM Contact WHERE Id =: contactIds];
            if(contacts.size() == 0)
                return System.Label.Pardot_Error_Invalid_Contact;
    
                String endpoint;
                String requestBody;
                                    
                
                Map<String, String> headerParameters= new Map<String, String>{'Pardot-Business-Unit-Id' => '0Uv560000004C98CAE'};
                if(contacts.size() == 1){  
                    Contact contactRecord = contacts[0];  
               
     
                endpoint = 'callout:APEX_Pardot_Credential/prospect/version/4/do/create/email/' + contactRecord.Email;
                requestBody = 'first_name=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(contactRecord.FirstName,Constants.UTF_8)
                                        + '&last_name=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(contactRecord.LastName,Constants.UTF_8)
                                        + '&email=' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(contactRecord.Email,Constants.UTF_8)
                                        + '&crm_owner_fid=' + contactRecord.OwnerId;
                                                              
          
            } else {
            
                endpoint = pardotTrackingConfigs[0].Batch_Create_Prospect_Endpoint__c;
                requestBody = '';
                for(Contact contactRecord:contacts){
                                                            
                    requestBody = requestBody +'{"email":"' + EncodingUtil.urlEncode(contactRecord.Email,Constants.UTF_8) 
                                              + '","first_name":"'+ EncodingUtil.urlEncode(contactRecord.FirstName,Constants.UTF_8) 
                                              + '","last_name":"'+ EncodingUtil.urlEncode(contactRecord.LastName,Constants.UTF_8) 
                                              + '","crm_owner_fid":"'+ contactRecord.OwnerId+ '"},'
                                              + '",},';
    
                    }
                    
                    requestBody = 'prospects={"prospects":['+ requestBody.removeEnd(',')+']}';
            }
            
            
            HttpRequest request= HTTPRequestBuilder.buildHTTPRequest(endpoint, Constants.POST,
                                                                            Constants.APPLICATIONX_WWW_FORM_URLENCODED,
                                                                            headerParameters, requestBody);
                    
            HttpResponse response = HTTPService_PARDOT.send(request);
            return HTTPResponseParser_PARDOT.parseCreateRecordResponse(response);
        }
    }
```

**And that uses this class, this line shows up on the error :**

**response = http.send(request);**

```
public with sharing class HTTPService_PARDOT {
        
    //HttpResponse instance
    
        public static HttpResponse response;
        
        //boolean to indicate whether or not the callout should execute while in a unit test
        public static boolean sendCalloutInUnitTest = false;
    
        public static HttpResponse send(HttpRequest request) {
        //Create a HTTP instance and do callout
            Http http = new Http();
        
            //Check whether or not this should send the callout
            if(!Test.isRunningTest() || sendCalloutInUnitTest)
                
                response = http.send(request);
    
            return response;
        }
    }
```

It all works fine when run in the sandbox. Any idea what I can do to get it to deploy/test properly ?

Thank you.

Comment: Without seeing your test it's hard to say - I'd edit and add the test code.  Also, are you saying this code works live in your sandbox, or the test runs without errors in the sandbox?

Comment: @VictorLockwood - Thank you very much for your response. I have included the test code and have also rewritten my original post to try and make the most sense of this. I'm trying to lay it out as best I can because I have a feeling it is something that can be handled in testing. I'm saying this code works correctly in the sandbox live, but it errors-out when I attempt to deploy it. Right now, that line in httpservice_PARDOT which is referenced causes all of the problems. For some reason, that seems to be causing problems. It's used by the Http_Pardot_Utility class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is in `@TestSetup` you are inserting records and then in testMethod you are making a callout, and the transactions here are not separated. And as we know that we are not allowed to make a callout after doing DML, hence you are getting that error.

To separate transactions of  `@TestSetup` and your testMethod you need to use `Test.startTest();` and `Test.stopTest();`.

So wrap your whole `testSetupData` inside `startTest` and `stopTest`.

Like this:

```
@TestSetup
static void testSetupData(){
    Test.startTest();
    // Create a unique User records
    String uniqueUserName = 'standarduser' + DateTime.now().getTime() + '@testorg.com';
    // This code runs as the system user
    Profile profileTest = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name='Standard User'];

    User userFrom = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com', EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8',
            LastName='Testing', LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = profileTest.Id,
            TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', UserName=uniqueUserName);

    User userTo = new User(Alias = 'standt', Email='standarduser@testorg.com',EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', LastName='Testing',
            LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', LocaleSidKey='en_US', ProfileId = profileTest.Id, TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles',
            UserName=uniqueUserName);

    //Create Account records
    List<Account> accounts = new List<Account>();
    accounts.add(new Account(Name = 'AccountTest1'));
    accounts.add(new Account(Name = 'AccountTest2'));
    accounts.add(new Account(Name = 'AccountTest3'));
    insert accounts;

    //Create program records
    List<Program__c> programs = new List<Program__c>();
    programs.add(new Program__c(Name = 'ProgramDemo1',Buyer__c = accounts[0].Id));
    programs.add(new Program__c(Name = 'ProgramDemo2' , Buyer__c = accounts[1].Id));
    programs.add(new Program__c(Name = 'ProgramDemo3',Buyer__c = accounts[2].Id));
    insert programs;

    //Create contact records
    List<Contact> contacts = new List<Contact>();
    contacts.add(new Contact(FirstName = 'Contact' , LastName = 'Test1' , Email = 'sarj@gmail.com'));
    contacts.add(new Contact(FirstName = 'Contact' , LastName = 'Test2' , Email = 'sarj1@gmail.com'));
    contacts.add(new Contact(FirstName = 'Contact' , LastName = 'Test3' , Email = 'sarj2@gmail.com'));
    insert contacts;


    //Create program communication records
    List<Program_Communication__c> proCommunications = new List<Program_Communication__c>();
    proCommunications.add(new Program_Communication__c(Name='proCommunication1',Program__c = programs[0].Id , Logo_Public_Url__c = '&versionId=06856000000FXaEAAW&operationContext=DELIVERY&page=0&d=/a/560000008V0q/IQoWYqi_cIVSBG8rUl4x78lmbl0vtdIwnu7WpHoag0M&oid=00D560000009n7iEAA&dpt=null', Welcome_Message__c='Have a nice day.', Reply_to_Email__c= userTo.Id , From_Email__c= userFrom.Id));
    proCommunications.add(new Program_Communication__c(Name='proCommunication2',Program__c = programs[0].Id , Logo_Public_Url__c = '&versionId=06856000000FXaEAAW&operationContext=DELIVERY&page=0&d=/a/560000008V0q/IQoWYqi_cIVSBG8rUl4x78lmbl0vtdIwnu7WpHoag0M&oid=00D560000009n7iEAA&dpt=null',Welcome_Message__c='Have a nice day. Have a nice day.', Reply_to_Email__c= userTo.Id , From_Email__c= userFrom.Id));
    proCommunications.add(new Program_Communication__c(Name='proCommunication3',Program__c = programs[0].Id , Logo_Public_Url__c = '&versionId=06856000000FXaEAAW&operationContext=DELIVERY&page=0&d=/a/560000008V0q/IQoWYqi_cIVSBG8rUl4x78lmbl0vtdIwnu7WpHoag0M&oid=00D560000009n7iEAA&dpt=null',Welcome_Message__c='Have a nice day.', Reply_to_Email__c= userTo.Id , From_Email__c= userFrom.Id));
    insert proCommunications;

    //Create program contact role records
    List<Program_Contact_Role__c> proContactRoles = new List<Program_Contact_Role__c>();
    proContactRoles.add(new Program_Contact_Role__c(Name = 'ProContactRole1',Program_Name__c = programs[0].Id , Contact__c = contacts[0].Id));
    proContactRoles.add(new Program_Contact_Role__c(Name = 'ProContactRole2',Program_Name__c = programs[0].Id , Contact__c = contacts[1].Id));
    proContactRoles.add(new Program_Contact_Role__c(Name = 'ProContactRole3',Program_Name__c = programs[0].Id , Contact__c = contacts[2].Id));
    insert proContactRoles;

    //Create program communication recipients records
    List<Program_Communication_Recipients__c> proCommRecipients = new List<Program_Communication_Recipients__c>();
    proCommRecipients.add(new Program_Communication_Recipients__c(Program_Communication__c = proCommunications[0].Id,Receipient__c = proContactRoles[0].Id));
    proCommRecipients.add(new Program_Communication_Recipients__c(Program_Communication__c = proCommunications[0].Id,Receipient__c = proContactRoles[1].Id));
    proCommRecipients.add(new Program_Communication_Recipients__c(Program_Communication__c = proCommunications[0].Id,Receipient__c = proContactRoles[2].Id));
    insert proCommRecipients;

    Test.stopTest();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't you want to do the Test.startTest() and Test.stopTest() calls inside testUpdateContactPCRController()?  Either way should separate the transactions I believe but I'm just wondering what's best practice.  Also for Zoom_v, I'm not putting this in a new answer because this doesn't address what you're asking, but the 'testMethod' way of building tests is deprecated - the new way is with the @isTest annotation: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_isTest.htm

Comment: Thank you so much both of you. I really appreciate it. This is the first time I've ever experienced Test.stopTest(). Very grateful !!! I applied the changes @Nagendra showed in his example and it worked perfectly ! Thanks again !!!